# Installing the sunspot rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

I've problem installing sunspot. I included these in my Gem file:

```
gem 'sunspot_solr', github: 'sunspot/sunspot', branch: 'master'
gem 'sunspot_rails', github: 'sunspot/sunspot', branch: 'master'
```

Installed the bundle. But when I try to install it `rails generate sunspot_rails:install` an error pops up saying `uninitialized constant Sunspot::Rails::Application (NameError)`

For the full error, read the snippet below

```
/home/aws003/Desktop/Raghuveer/Sunspot/config/application.rb:10:in `<module:Sunspot>': uninitialized constant Sunspot::Rails::Application (NameError)

from /home/aws003/Desktop/Raghuveer/Sunspot/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'

from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:43:in `require'

from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:43:in `<top (required)>'

from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

What should I do to solve this?

Comment: Please include your config/application.rb, and also try removing the github and branch.

Answer (score 1):

Name your project differently. This is a namespace collision. You have your project named Sunspot.